# How to filter Array using ToLowerCase in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, filter

I've custom array in TypeScript.

```
 array = [{ name: "Hardik", city: null, job: null },
  { name: "John", city: "Ahmedabad", job: "IT" },
  { name: "Margie", city: "Mumbai", job: "CA" },
  { name: "Creature", city: "Banglore", job: null },
  { name: "Smooth", city: null, job: null }];
```

I want to filter this array base on city and job. Also, I need to check case-insensitive. so I convert to ToLowerCase.

```
this.filter = this.array.filter(i =>
  i.job.toLowerCase().indexOf('ca') != -1 ||
  i.city.toLowerCase().indexOf('ahmedabad') != -1 
)
```

Which is working correct if the columns are not null. If the column is null, it gives error, can not toLowerCase() of null. so, I check first where columns is null or not.

```
this.filter = this.array.filter(i =>
      i["job"] != null ? i.job.toLowerCase().indexOf('ca') != -1 : false ||
      i["city"] != null ? i.city.toLowerCase().indexOf('ahmedabad') != -1 : false
    )
```

But it gives wrong output.

```
[ { "name": "Margie", "city": "Mumbai", "job": "CA" } ]
```

Expected output is:

```
 [{ name: "John", city: "Ahmedabad", job: "IT" },
  { name: "Margie", city: "Mumbai", job: "CA" }]
```

link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/filter-with-tolowercase-and-null?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the correct answer by changing your code as follow:

```
this.filter = this.array.filter(i =>
  (i["job"] && i.job.toLowerCase().indexOf('ca') != -1) ||
  (i["city"] && i.city.toLowerCase().indexOf('ahmedabad') != -1) 
)
```

Comment: The specific issue here is [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), where `||` binds more tightly than `? :`.  So `true ? false : false || true` is interpreted as `true ? false : (false || true)` and not `(true ? false: false) || true`.  When in doubt, use parentheses.

Comment: Thank-you for the explanation @jcalz. Although I got it working, but I wasn't sure why OP's solution wasn't working. Now I get it.

Comment: Yes, If I used Parantheses, even my answer works. :( silly me

Answer (score 0):

```
this.filter = this.array.filter(i =>
  (i["job"] != null ? i.job.toLowerCase().indexOf('ca') != -1 : false) ||
  (i["city"] != null ? i.city.toLowerCase().indexOf('ahmedabad') != -1 : false)
)
```

problem is due to Operator precedence

Comment: Please explain why/how this fixes the problem